# Download file from Google Cloud Storage via backend redirect

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, redirect

Frontend button triggers backend creation of a file, on Google Cloud Storage.
I want to redirect to the download-url.

Url works when pasted into new tab, but the download don't start when redirected.

```
def get(self):
  # create file/url
  url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/..." # works!
  self.redirect(url)
```

**Update:**
I now believe this is a CORS issue in frontend.

Comment: What kind of Class is this in?  Is it a `webapp.RequestHandler`?

Comment: webapp2.RequestHandler (slightly modified)